# Setting up a Todo List server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm fairly new to Javascript, Node.js and JSON. I'm supposed to build some sort of Todo list application, where the user sends his todo to a server. I've already created the HTML and Javascript to execute the basic operation without the server.

I'm using the following program/languages in order to complete my assignment:

- Vagrant (various NPM modules)
- VirtualBox
- Javascript (jQuery)

**Currently i'm trying to send the data via the following lines of code:**

```
    //Create (simplified) "task"
    item["id"] = task.dataset.id;
    item["taskname"] = task.dataset.taskname;
    item = JSON.stringify(item);

    //Send code
    $.ajax({
            url: '/addtodo',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            data: item 
    });
```

Where as on the receiving side, **I try to receive the data using the following lines of code:**

```
app.post("/addtodo", function (req, res) {
    var newTodo = req.body;

    fs.writeFile("Somefile.json",  JSON.parse(newTodo), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            res.json({"message":"Storing data failed"});
        } else {
            res.json({"message":"Data stored successfully"});
       }
    });
 });
```

My objective is to get something like this in "Somefile.json"

```
[{
        "id"    : 2,
        "taskname"  : "Example task 2",
    },
{
        "id"    : 2,
        "taskname"  : "Example task 2",
    },
]
```

For now I get either errors or it changes the Somefile.json into [object Object].
Anyone care to explain what I did wrong and how I should fix it

Edit:
If I do not use JSON.parse i get : `[object Object]`

If I use JSON.stringify I get `{"{\"id\":\"6\",\"taskname\":\"1234\"}":""}`

Comment: `JSON.parse(newTodo)` out puts a javascript object. You need it in the form of JSON, so if it's already JSON, the `JSON.parse()` portion isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the

```
JSON.parse(newToDo);
```

Use

```
JSON.stringify(newToDo);
```

This function will convert the object into a string and will give you the desired output.

Comment: Actually, because he **sends** it as JSON there is no need to use stringify (req.body is string anyway).

Comment: If I use stringify everything turns into one long line i.e: {"all the data" : ""}, If I let it be, it turns into [object Object]

Comment: Use this then JSON.stringify(newToDo,null,2);